# How to use az network nsg rule to wait until a certain IP range appears in the sourceAddressPrefixes list?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I know how to test for the presence for an IP range in an NSG rule:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ az network nsg rule show -g $rg_name --nsg-name $nsg_name -n $rule_name --query "sourceAddressPrefixes[?@=='10.98.48.0/20']"
[
  "10.98.48.0/20"
]
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Now I want to wait for it (and it is currently there), but the wait never ends:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ az network nsg rule wait -g $rg_name --nsg-name $nsg_name -n $rule_name --custom "sourceAddressPrefixes[?@=='10.98.48.0/20']"
 | Waiting ..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue when I tried in my environment.

After a workaround on this, I found a way to resolve it by adding `--timeout` flag according to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nsg-rule-wait).

So I created a new nsg rule using below `AzCLI` command.

```bash
az network nsg rule create -g <resourcegroup> --nsg-name <networksecuritygroup> -n <NsgRule> --priority 4096 --source-address-prefixes 208.130.28.0/24 --source-port-ranges 80 --destination-address-prefixes '*' --destination-port-ranges 80 8080 --access Deny --protocol Tcp --description "Deny"
```

[image]

Verified the created rule using `az network nsg rule` show command as shown:

```bash
az network nsg rule show -g <resourcegroup> --nsg-name <Nsgname> -n <NsgRule>
```

[image]

***Mainly, the command "az network nsg rule wait" itself says that it will place the CLI in a state of waiting until a condition is met.***

So here I provided the `timeout` flag as shown below to know the status of the operation, which made the job easier.

And also, You need to give `'( )'` expression for the `sourceAddressprefixes Ip` because `()` expression contains the condition to match.

The `[?()]` filter expression is used here to select only the elements that match the specified condition.

*I modified the command as below:*

```bash
az network nsg rule wait -g <resourcegroup> --nsg-name <NSG> -n <NsgRule> --custom "sourceAddressPrefixes[?(@=='<addressprefix>')]" --timeout 60
```

> Default timeout value is 3600 sec as per the above given MSDoc.

***Output:***

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nsg-rule-wait) for the relevant `az network` commands.

***Note***: If the problem still persists, restart the Az CLI and run the command again.